# Random Numbers Java

Tags: java, random

Just a quick question, i'm working on a project in which the user inputs a number, which in this case is x, then, when they click the 'calculate' button it is to do the following:

1. Generate x random numbers
2. Put each number into an array list
3. Print out the array list

Heres what i have thus far:

```
String input;
int int1;
input = Input.getText();
int1 = Integer.parseInt(input);
```

That just gets the user input and converts it to an integer.

Comment: Do research on Java `Random` class and how to use it. Then come back if you have further questions.

Comment: Also learn how to use `ArrayList.add()`, and `for` loops. :-)

Comment: You can try Math.random() - which outputs an integer in the range [0,1) and scale it to fit your needs.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young Don't forget `Scanner`, or some other method of reading the user input.

Comment: @manan s/integer/double/

Answer (score -2):

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int userNum;
ArrayList<Integer> array = new ArrayList<Integer>();

userNum = input.nextInt();
input.close();
for (int i = 0; i < userNum; i++) {
    array.add(Math.random());
    System.out.println(array.get(i));
}
```

You have to import java.util.Math, I think.

Comment: `Math` is _not_ in `java.util`. Also, the use of `ArrayList<Integer>` is wrong: it should be `List<Double>`. Thus: `List<Double> nums = new ArrayList<>();`. Also, it's wrong to manually call `input.close()` like that, since it's not exception-safe. The standard way to do it is to use `try (Scanner input = ...) { ... }`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot Math.random() generate's doubles unless you specify otherwise. And `Math` is part of `java.lang` - totally spaced that. And I've always used `ArrayList<Integer> array = new ArrayList<Integer>();` just wouldn't work in this case because doubles are being generated, not integers.

Comment: You may have "always" used `ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();` but it's still not best practice. Use interface types like `List` when possible. The use of `new ArrayList<>()` is also correct for Java 7 and means you don't have to duplicate the `Integer`.

Comment: I'm not saying it's how it's supposed to use. Thanks for the criticism though, I like having input like this, it helps open my eyes more :)